# How to fix this 400 Bad status error?

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

The following image shows the error and the `cfdump` output,

[image]

Here is my JSON Response :

```
{
  "properties": [{
    "property": "email",
    "value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
  }, {
    "property": "firstname",
    "value": "Adrian"
  }, {
    "property": "lastname",
    "value": "Mott"
  }, {
    "property": "website",
    "value": "http://hubspot.com"
  }, {
    "property": "company",
    "value": "HubSpot"
  }, {
    "property": "phone",
    "value": "555-122-2323"
  }, {
    "property": "address",
    "value": "25 First Street"
  }, {
    "property": "city",
    "value": "Cambridge"
  }, {
    "property": "state",
    "value": "MA"
  }, {
    "property": "zip",
    "value": "02139"
  }]
}
```

Here is the code I am using. I am setting values using `cfset` and then posting the data using `cfhttp`,

```
<cfset stFields='{
           {
            "properties": [
                {
                    "property": "email",
                    "value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
                },
                {
                    "property": "firstname",
                    "value": "Adrian"
                },
                {
                    "property": "lastname",
                    "value": "Mott"
                },
                {
                    "property": "website",
                    "value": "http://hubspot.com"
                },
                {
                    "property": "company",
                    "value": "HubSpot"
                },
                {
                    "property": "phone",
                    "value": "555-122-2323"
                },
                {
                    "property": "address",
                    "value": "25 First Street"
                },
                {
                    "property": "city",
                    "value": "Cambridge"
                },
                {
                    "property": "state",
                    "value": "MA"
                },
                {
                    "property": "zip",
                    "value": "02139"
                }
            ]
        }
    }'>

  <cfhttp url="https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/?hapikey=demo" method="post" result="httpResp" timeout="60">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(stFields)#">
  </cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResp#" label="HTTP response">
```

After the dump, it shows the error `400 Bad request Access`.
Please help me to rectify this Error.

Comment: bad requests are malformed requests. check for the api documentation to figure out the the request structure.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh             
The code sample below represents some example JSON with 
standard fields to pass in the body of your request in 
order to create a new contact.  Note the structure of 
the JSON that you must pass in to HubSpot:
{ "properties": [
{
"property": "email",
"value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
  },
  {
  "property": "firstname",
  "value": "Adrian"
    },
    {
  "property": "lastname",
  "value": "Mott"
       }
       ]
       }
        If the request succeeds, you'll get an HTTP 200 response 
with a JSON object.this only give in documentation bro.

Comment: could I change Cfset in anyother formats..

Comment: Why do you have two curly braces `{` wrapping your JSON? Should just be one right. And why are you using `serializeJSON()` when you are creating the JSON response yourself?

Comment: Bro,I am  confused which one you are mentioning...could you rearrange the cfset correctly I will try it please.

Comment: in cfset if i don't put '{ }' brace  it shows page error in cold fusion.

Comment: Look at your dump of the JSON. You have two curly brackets `{ {` at the very beginning and two `} }` at the very end. There should only be one I think. Take all of those carriage returns out of your `cfset` statement. Just make it one long line. You may be getting control characters mixed in.

Comment: yeah I remove those two braces at begin and end then put in json validator,it is valid. But it adds because of cfset = '{ }'>.If I don't put this braces or apostrophe.it throws page error.how to change it.

Comment: you need one brace, just not two.

Comment: k bro...is any other issue other than braces ..i have to remove the serializejson also...

Answer (score 0):

Create a structure instead of a string. Use CFDump to see it is correct. Like so:

```
<cfset stFields = {
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "email",
            "value": "testingapis@hubspot.com"
        },
        {
            "property": "firstname",
            "value": "Adrian"
        },
        {
            "property": "lastname",
            "value": "Mott"
        },
        {
            "property": "website",
            "value": "http://hubspot.com"
        },
        {
            "property": "company",
            "value": "HubSpot"
        },
        {
            "property": "phone",
            "value": "555-122-2323"
        },
        {
            "property": "address",
            "value": "25 First Street"
        },
        {
            "property": "city",
            "value": "Cambridge"
        },
        {
            "property": "state",
            "value": "MA"
        },
        {
            "property": "zip",
            "value": "02139"
        }
    ]
}>
<cfdump var="#stfields#">
```

Then in your cfhttp use the serialized version of that structure. You can CFDump that as a test as well.

```
<cfdump var="#serializeJSON(stfields)#">
```